# Web Push Notifications InvalidSignature

Tags: javascript, php, html, web, notifications

I cannot seem to get push notifications to work whatever I try...

This is the error code.
`{"code":401,"errno":109,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"InvalidSignature","more_info":"http://autopush.readthedocs.io/en/latest/http.html#error-codes"}`

It appears that the issue has something to do with ether a key mismatch or invalid signature.

Here are some of the resources I was using:
https://blog.mozilla.org/services/2016/08/23/sending-vapid-identified-webpush-notifications-via-mozillas-push-service/

https://autopush.readthedocs.io/en/latest/http.html#error-codes

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc8292/

I'm generating the public/private keys as so:

```
    function base64url_encode($data) {
        return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '=');
    }

    function generateVapidKeys(){
        if(file_exists('vapid.json')){
            $vapidKeys = json_decode(file_get_contents('vapid.json'));
            return base64url_encode(hex2bin('04'.$vapidKeys->x.$vapidKeys->y));

        }else{
            $keyPair = openssl_pkey_new([
                'digest_alg' => 'sha256',
                'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_EC,
                'curve_name' => 'prime256v1', // P-256 curve
            ]);
        }

        $privateKeyDetails = openssl_pkey_get_details($keyPair);

        $x = str_pad(bin2hex($privateKeyDetails['ec']['x']), 64, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $y = str_pad(bin2hex($privateKeyDetails['ec']['y']), 64, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $d = str_pad(bin2hex($privateKeyDetails['ec']['d']), 64, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

        file_put_contents('vapid.json', json_encode([
            'x' => $x,
            'y' => $y,
            'd' => $d,
        ], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));

        return base64url_encode(hex2bin('04'.$x.$y));
    }

    $publicKey = generateVapidKeys();
```

And finally here is my Notification send:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

    function generate_jwt($headers, $payload, $privateKey){
        $headers_encoded = base64url_encode(json_encode($headers));
        $payload_encoded = base64url_encode(json_encode($payload));
        
        //$signature = hash_hmac('SHA256', "$headers_encoded.$payload_encoded", $secret, true);
        openssl_sign("$headers_encoded.$payload_encoded", $signature, $privateKey, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);
        $signature_encoded = base64url_encode($signature);
        
        return "$headers_encoded.$payload_encoded.$signature_encoded";
    }

    function is_jwt_valid($jwt, $publicKey){
        $tokenParts = explode('.', $jwt);
    
        // check the expiration time - note this will cause an error if there is no 'exp' claim in the jwt
        $expires = json_decode(base64_decode($tokenParts[1]))->exp < time();//($expires - time()) < 0;

        $signature = openssl_verify($tokenParts[0].'.'.$tokenParts[1], base64_decode($tokenParts[2]), $publicKey, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);
        
        if($expires || !$signature){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    function generateVapidToken($url, $privateKey) {
    
        $expiration = time() + (12 * 60 * 60);  // 12 hours
    
        $header = [
            'alg' => 'ES256',
            'typ' => 'JWT',
        ];

        $body = [
            'aud' => $url,
            'exp' => $expiration,
            'sub' => 'mailto:your_email@example.com',
        ];

        return generate_jwt($header, $body, $privateKey);
    }
    
    function base64url_encode($data) {
        return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '=');
    }


    // Assuming you have a database connection established

    // Function to send a push notification
    function sendPushNotification($subscription, $payload)
    {

        $parse = parse_url($subscription->endpoint);
        $url = $parse['scheme'].'://'.$parse['host'];//.pathinfo(parse_url($parse['path'], PHP_URL_PATH))['dirname'];
        echo $url.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;

        $vapidKeys = json_decode(file_get_contents('vapid.json'));

        //print_r(json_encode($vapidKeys, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));


        $keyPair = openssl_pkey_new([
            'ec' => [
                'digest_alg' => 'sha256',
                'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_EC,
                'curve_name' => 'prime256v1', // P-256 curve
                'x' => hex2bin($vapidKeys->x),
                'y' => hex2bin($vapidKeys->y),
                'd' => hex2bin($vapidKeys->d)
            ]
        ]);

        $privateKeyDetails = openssl_pkey_get_details($keyPair);

        openssl_pkey_export($keyPair, $privateKey);
        $token = generateVapidToken($url, $privateKey);
        //openssl_sign('HELLO WORLD', $signature, $privateKey, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);
        echo $token;

        echo PHP_EOL;
        echo PHP_EOL;

        $publicKey = openssl_pkey_get_public($privateKeyDetails['key']);
        $verified = is_jwt_valid($token, $publicKey);
        //$verified = openssl_verify('HELLO WORLD', $signature, $publicKey, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);


        echo 'Token Valid: '.(($verified) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
        echo PHP_EOL;
        echo PHP_EOL;


        $publicKey = base64url_encode(hex2bin('04'.$vapidKeys->x.$vapidKeys->y));
        echo $publicKey;


        echo PHP_EOL;
        echo PHP_EOL;

        $headers = [
            //'Authorization: WebPush '.$token,
            'Authorization: vapid t='.$token.',k='.$publicKey,
            //'Authorization: key=' . $subscription->keys->auth,
            //'Crypto-Key: p256ecdsa='.$publicKey.';dh='.$subscription->keys->auth,//$subscription->keys->p256dh,
            'Content-Type: application/json',
        ];

        /*
        $notification = [
            'title' => 'Your Notification Title',
            'body' => 'Your Notification Body',
            'icon' => 'path/to/icon.png',
        ];
        */

        $data = [
            'notification' => $payload,
            //'applicationServerKey' => $vapidKeys->publicKey
        ];

        $options = [
            CURLOPT_URL => $subscription->endpoint,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($payload),
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        ];

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
    
        if ($result === false) {
            echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL;
        } else {
            echo 'Push notification sent successfully!' . PHP_EOL;
        }


        print_r($result);
    }

    // Example payload
    $notificationPayload = [
        'title' => 'New Notification',
        'body' => 'This is the body of the notification.',
        'icon' => 'icon.png'
    ];

    if(file_exists('endpoints.json')){
        $subscriptions = json_decode(file_get_contents('endpoints.json'));

        // Send push notifications to all stored subscriptions
        foreach ($subscriptions as $subscription) {
            sendPushNotification($subscription, $notificationPayload);
        }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for this specific issue was the way I was generating the JWT.I needed to modify the signature differently.

```
    function generate($headers, $payload, $privateKey){
        $message = self::base64url_encode(json_encode($headers)).'.'.self::base64url_encode(json_encode($payload));
        openssl_sign($message, $signature, $privateKey, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);

        $components = [];
        $pos = 0;
        $size = strlen($signature);
        while ($pos < $size) {
            $constructed = (ord($signature[$pos]) >> 5) & 0x01;
            $type = ord($signature[$pos++]) & 0x1f;
            $len = ord($signature[$pos++]);
            if ($len & 0x80) {
                $n = $len & 0x1f;
                $len = 0;
                while ($n-- && $pos < $size) $len = ($len << 8) | ord($signature[$pos++]);
            }
    
            if ($type == 0x03) {
                $pos++;
                $components[] = substr($signature, $pos, $len - 1);
                $pos += $len - 1;
            } else if (! $constructed) {
                $components[] = substr($signature, $pos, $len);
                $pos += $len;
            }
        }
        foreach ($components as &$c) $c = str_pad(ltrim($c, "\x00"), 32, "\x00", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    
        return $message . '.' . self::base64url_encode(implode('', $components));
        
        //return "$headers_encoded.$payload_encoded.$signature_encoded";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure is wrong.

1. keypair (vapid) generate only once but you generate every time when send notification.
2. I don't see your code for get subscription so i guess you mock manually. we can't do that because we can get subscription from browser only (by javascript).

To make push API working we should.

1. generate keypair save `private key` to safe place on server. `pubic key` is require for create subscription in browser you can save them in javascript code or any method.
2. create subscription in `browser/user agent` (it's done by end user) and send to server save them to DB or any storage.
3. send notification create `http request` contain `notification payload` (payload might different for each `browser/user agent`)  follow rfc standard and send them to `endpoint` in subscription.

Here some resources

- https://web-push-book.gauntface.com/
- https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php

Don't confuse between Push API and Notification API.
It's different API. We could Push but don't need to use pushed data in Notification API. So you could push any data from server and convert them to Notification on browser.

Comment: Ya, I got dinged when asking the question because I provided too much code lol.

I generate the VAPID only once

From my understanding we have an application keypair and a user keypair and we get the user keypair from the subscription response?

Comment: @DrBrad Yes, enduser's key is in `pushSubscription` object and `applicationServerKey` is your application `public key` in binary format [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PushManager/subscribe#examples).